# Dart: generics abstract static methods

Tags: oop, dart

**Dears**

I want to have abstract generic class with the following pattern
My phone model is as follows:

```
  class Phone extends ModelInterface {
  ...

  @override
  static dynamic getErrorInstance(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Phone.fromErrors(map);
  }

  @override
  static dynamic getResponseInstance(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Phone.fromMap(map);
  }
}
```

As you can see the Phone model extends ModelInterface and there are two overriden methods `getErrorInstance` and `getResponseInstance`

These two methods are defined as static in the `ModelInterface` abstract class

```
abstract class ModelInterface {
  static dynamic getErrorInstance(Map<String, dynamic> map) {}
  static dynamic getResponseInstance(Map<String, dynamic> map) {}
}
```

What I wanted to do is to create a generic method that builds the object based on response type shown below

```
abstract class Base {
  ...

  T getModel<T extends ModelInterface>(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (hasErrors(map)) {
      return T.getErrorInstance(map);
    }

    return T.getResponseInstance(map);
  }
}
```

And the client for this method `getModel` shown below

```
class UserAuth extends Base {
  Future<Phone> registerPhone(Phone phone) async {
    String url = Routes.phoneUrl;
    String body = json.encode(phone.toMap());
    final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: Routes.headers);
    final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    // here I want the generic type to be phone
    return getModel<Phone>(responseBody);
  }
}
```

However I am getting this error

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can not override static methods.

Comment: @Tidder how would I approach the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I fixed it by passing in another generic Parameter such as below

```
  T getModel<T extends ModelInterface>(Map<String, dynamic> map, T) {
    if (hasErrors(map)) {
      return T.getErrorInstance(map);
    }

    return T.getResponseInstance(map);
  }
```

And for the client code I added the below

```
class UserAuth extends Base {
  Future<Phone> registerPhone(Phone phone) async {
    String url = Routes.phoneUrl;
    String body = json.encode(phone.toMap());
    final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: Routes.headers);
    final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

    return getModel<Phone>(responseBody, Phone.empty());
  }
}
```